# Decode json PHP find output only arrays containing POST string value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Im trying to make a simple JSON retriever.

So here is what im trying to do.
When i type for example
Japan. and i post the data to php.
I want it to load the json it has and search arrays for values containing this country Japan

Sending a smaller cut down json array containing only results containing this value back to the page.

The key is Country,
Example json

```js
{
"1": {
        "country": "America",
        "Name": "Harry",
        "Age": "41"
    },
"2": {
        "country": "America",
        "Name": "ben",
        "Age": "40"
    },
"3": {
        "country": "Japan",
        "Name": "taka",
        "Age": "48"
    },
"4": {
        "country": "Japan",
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "41"
    },
"5": {
        "country": "America",
        "Name": "Ted",
        "Age": "41"
    },
"6": {
        "country": "America",
        "Name": "Simon",
        "Age": "41"
    }
}
```

```js
var country = $(".country").val();  
$.ajax ({
      url: json.php,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          'find': country,
      },
      success: function (results) {
          console.log(results);
      },
      fail: function(data) {
          console.log( data.responseText );
          console.log( 'Request Failed' + data.statusText );
      }
  })
```

```html
<input name="country" class="country" type="text" placeholder="type country"></input>
```

```js
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
$jsonurl = "data.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$find = $_POST["find"];
$decode = json_decode($json, true);



$results = array_filter($decode[''], function($country) {
  return $country['country'] == $find;
});


var_dump($results);
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You are sending the `country` value with POST request headers. In your PHP `S_POST['find']` should contain the keyword. Not GET. After you've decoded the JSON string, it'll be an array. So you need to loop through the array and have it return any data where the country array key matches the keyword value back into a new array. Json encode that array and send it back to your ajax function so you have the data available to you in JS.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try with $_POST but i know my example isnt correct.
But thanks for replying :) i hope i can figure this out soon.

Comment: Well no, your example will not work. Not even with `$_POST['find']`. Look at your JSON string. If you decode that, the array would be `$decode["0"]["country"]`. You are looking for the value, not the array key as its hard coded into country.

Comment: Okay so iv updated the first post with what iv got So far.
But im still not getting much luck.

Comment: Did you do proper debugging? `echo $_POST["find"];` to see if PHP is receiving the correct value. `echo json_encode($decode);` to see if it contains what you expect. You have to go through all of it in order to figure out where the issue is. Not so sure about `array_filter($decode['']` either. Looks like you're not passing the array here cause of the empty array key.

Comment: i need pass all arrays. so its empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample using which you can achieve your requirement.

```
$my_json = '{
           "1": {"country": "America","Name": "Harry","Age": "41"},
           "2": {"country": "America","Name": "ben","Age": "40"},
           "3": {"country": "Japan","Name": "taka","Age": "48"},
           "4": {"country": "Japan","Name": "John","Age": "41"},
           "5": {"country": "America","Name": "Ted","Age": "41"},
           "6": {"country": "America","Name": "Simon","Age": "41"}
        }';
    $json_arr =  json_decode($my_json);
    $item = array();
    foreach($j as $k=>$struct) {
        if ('Japan' == $struct->country) {
            $item[$k] = $struct;                
        }
    }
    echo 'Object Array form::';
    echo '---------------------------';     
    print_r(array_values($item));   
    echo 'Json form::';
    echo '---------------------------';     
    echo json_encode(array_values($item));
```

Comment: Help the OP understand how this solves the problem by explaining the code you've written.

Comment: If you are going to copy / paste code, at least correct the variable names in it. `foreach($j`??? Also, you cannot `print_r` an array when it has to return data to Ajax. And lastly, you cannot return data to ajax multiple times. This answer is almost completely wrong.

Comment: I tried your example exactly how it is. but it seems its not working.
Thanks for the input though :)